# Upload image into database

Tags: java, mysql, file, spring-mvc, upload

I'm trying to upload images into database and then show them on a jsp page. 
This is what I'm doing but all I got is the name of the image. Yeah, of course it can't simple as that. Do you have any suggestions for me?

JSP input file:

```
<spring:bind path="image">
    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><th><spring:message
                    code="label.image" /></th></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <form:label for="image" path="image">Image</form:label>
            <form:input path="image" type="file" />
            <form:errors path="image" class="control-label" />
        </div>
    </div>
</spring:bind>
```

DAO

```
@Override
public void save(Book book) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

String sql = "INSERT INTO Books(TENSACH, TACGIA, NHANXET, TINHTRANG, THELOAI, IMAGE) "
        + "VALUES ( :tensach, :tacgia, :nhanxet, :tinhtrang, :theloai, :image)";

namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(sql, getSqlParameterByModel(book), keyHolder);
book.setId(keyHolder.getKey().intValue());
}

private SqlParameterSource getSqlParameterByModel(Book book) {
    MapSqlParameterSource paramSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    paramSource.addValue("id", book.getId());
    paramSource.addValue("tensach", book.getTensach());
    paramSource.addValue("tacgia", book.getTacgia());
    paramSource.addValue("nhanxet", book.getNhanxet());
    paramSource.addValue("tinhtrang", book.getTinhtrang());
    paramSource.addValue("image", book.getImage());
    // join String
    paramSource.addValue("theloai", convertListToDelimitedString(book.getTheloai()));
    return paramSource;
}
```

Controller

```
public String saveBook(@ModelAttribute("bookForm") @Validated Book book, BindingResult result, Model model,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws IOException {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("genreList", populateDefaultModel(model));
        return "booksView/bookform";
    } else {

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("css", "success");
        if (book.isNew()) {
            // System.out.println(book.getId());
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "book added successfully!");
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "book updated successfully!");
        }
        bookService.saveOrUpdate(book);
        // POST/REDIRECT/GET
        return "redirect:/motsach/"; // + book.getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are so many questions here. Firstly, is your database column ready to accept an image? Is it of type `BLOB` or `LONGBLOB`? Secondly, have you verified that the image file is reaching your controller from the form? Have you done something like a debug print of the filesize to see that it's getting there? Thirdly, don't do this. Use the local filesystem or AWS S3 to store images.

Comment: 1. Yeah, it's LongBlob, I did some test, I can store an specific image by it's local address.
2. No, the image can't reach the controller, all I have in database is just a name.
3. Sorry but do you have any tutorial for me, I never use AWS S3 before.

Comment: I don't for Java sorry, I'm a PHP man. There's an SDK though and I've found Amazon's documentation to be good. [Java SDK for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/).